# Recuperar os primeiros elementos de uma lista de Integer

Tags: java, java-8, arraylist

Tenho uma lista `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
onde nela tenho mais de 40.000 registros.
Gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de pegar apenas os 10.000 primeiros.
Sei que tem como fazer um `for` e passar para uma nova lista, mas isso demanda muito processamento.

Teria um modo mais simples? Ou com Lambda?

Comment: Como você obtém 40k Itens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

// Adiciona os 40 mil registros...

List<Integer> list2 = list.stream().limit(10000).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Talvez, para evitar de gastar processamento, você prefira trabalhar com `Stream`s diretamente, evitando usar o [método `collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-). Neste caso, você faria isso:

```
Stream<Integer> stream = list.stream().limit(10000);
```

O segredo é usar o [método `limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-).

Answer (score 5):

De acordo com a documentação, tem a função:

```
List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
//Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.
```

Então, no seu caso:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
....
// Adicionar items ao array
....
List<Integer> array2 = array.subList(0,10000);
```

Comment: Acho que ele está querendo evitar cópias

Comment: Editei a solução.. Agora, tenho duas instâncias que apontam para a mesma lista. Fiz uns testes.. Ao mudar o item do array2, o array também é alterado - ou seja, possuem a mesma referência.

Comment: Ótima solução. :)

Comment: Valeu pelo aviso... Um erro bobo que ia custar um pouco de memória hehe

Comment: Esta é a solução mais eficiente e correta se a ideia é referenciar uma parte da lista sem alterar o conteúdo, por exemplo se você quer passar para um método. Ele cria apenas um novo objeto que aponta para o vetor interno original. No entanto, é bom sempre tentar trabalhar com listas imutáveis para evitar dores de cabeça, caso contrários os efeitos colaterais disso te farão ter pesadelos.